# Why need subnet when public IP available?

Tags: networking, router, ip, subnet

I am just entering into CCNA and there is a subtle concept of subnetting that is not going through my mind.

My issue is when we have a private IP address, why can't that do the job - why do we have to make use of subnetting?

Let's say for instance my public IP address is `83.47.203.123` but then I have a private IP of `192.168.0.4` assigned by my router.

Why do I need subnetting? Can't private IP's do the same job? I mean I still have around 16000 private IP's to play with.

Comment: Subnetting is a topic that is completely independent of Internet-routability of IP addresses.

Comment: Your question is somewhat baffling. Who said you need subnetting? What is being subnetted? You say, "Can't private IP's do the same job", but it's not clear what job you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of reasons you might want to break up a network's address space, be they public or private.

One of the big ones is public address-conservation, and the ability to rent out small blocks of addresses that can be grouped together. And you are right, if that is all you are considering, there is no reason to subnet a private IP range.

Other reasons to break up the network include:

- Organizing the network both physically and logically (for instance,
  servers vs workstations vs network hardware, VPN/External
  connections, central office vs satalite offices, etc).
- Security partitioning and firewalling
- Optimizing traffic flows (reducing the size of the broadcast domain,
  applying QOS or rate limiting policies)
- Integrating disparate network technologies (this subnet is
  Fiberchannel, that one is 802.5, and that one is wired ETHERNETII)
- and many more.

With Class C RFC1918 address spaces, you have up to 255 networks to choose from, so you could grant a whole class C to the datacenter and another to the 3rd floor workstation users, but consider a class A or B, where you get only one net with more than a 10 thousand (or millions for a 10./8) addresses each... it would be silly not to break that up.

As an aside, note that subnetting, is the act of dividing up a class-natural network into smaller parts. so a single class C could be divided into 2 126-host subnetworks, or 4 62-host subnetworks, or 8 30-host subnetworks, etc. Also note that the 192.168 range gives 255 networks, each with 253 hosts, not one network with 2^16 (65534) hosts. That would be defined as a supernet, and is not commonly used, except for route aggregation. Also note that while Classful networking is no longer strict like it used to be, an understanding of class is still important to understand subnetting, especially when you want to aggregate routes.

Comment: With a Class C address space, would you not have 255 *networks* to choose from, with 253 *addresses* on each network?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: Thanks Canadian Luke that answers my question. Thanks a lot for your help.